# DDS texture transparency rendered black Opengl

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha-transparency

I am currently trying to render textured objects in Opengl. Everything worked fine until I wanted to render a texture with transparency. Instead of showing the the object transparent it just rendered in total black.

The method fo loading the texture file is this:

```
//  structures for reading and information variables
char magic[4];
unsigned char header[124];
unsigned int width, height, linearSize, mipMapCount, fourCC;
unsigned char* dataBuffer;
unsigned int bufferSize;

fstream file(path, ios::in|ios::binary);

//  read magic and header
if (!file.read((char*)magic, sizeof(magic))){
    cerr<< "File " << path << " not found!"<<endl;
    return false;
}

if (magic[0]!='D' || magic[1]!='D' || magic[2]!='S' || magic[3]!=' '){
    cerr<< "File does not comply with dds file format!"<<endl;
    return false;
}

if (!file.read((char*)header, sizeof(header))){
    cerr<< "Not able to read file information!"<<endl;
    return false;
}

//  derive information from header
height = *(int*)&(header[8]);
width = *(int*)&(header[12]);
linearSize = *(int*)&(header[16]);
mipMapCount = *(int*)&(header[24]);
fourCC = *(int*)&(header[80]);

//  determine dataBuffer size
bufferSize = mipMapCount > 1 ? linearSize * 2 : linearSize;
dataBuffer = new unsigned char [bufferSize*2];

//  read data and close file
if (file.read((char*)dataBuffer, bufferSize/1.5))
    cout<<"Loading texture "<<path<<" successful"<<endl;
else{
    cerr<<"Data of file "<<path<<" corrupted"<<endl;
    return false;
}

file.close();

//  check pixel format
unsigned int format;

switch(fourCC){
case FOURCC_DXT1:
    format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT;
    break;
case FOURCC_DXT3:
    format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT;
    break;
case FOURCC_DXT5:
    format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT;
    break;
default:
    cerr << "Compression type not supported or corrupted!" << endl;
    return false;
}

glGenTextures(1, &ID);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);

unsigned int blockSize = (format == GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT) ? 8 : 16;
unsigned int offset = 0;

/* load the mipmaps */
for (unsigned int level = 0; level < mipMapCount && (width || height); ++level) {
    unsigned int size = ((width+3)/4)*((height+3)/4)*blockSize;
    glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, format, width, height,
                        0, size, dataBuffer + offset);

    offset += size;
    width  /= 2;
    height /= 2;
}

textureType = DDS_TEXTURE;

return true;
```

In the fragment shader I just set the gl_FragColor = texture2D( myTextureSampler, UVcoords )

I hope that there is an easy explanation such as some code missing. 
In the openGL initialization i glEnabled GL_Blend and set a blend function.

Does anyone have an idea of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the blend function is the correct function for what you are trying to accomplish. For what you've described that should be glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
2. You probably shouldn't set the blend function in your openGL initialization function but should wrap it around your draw calls like:

   ```
   glEnable(GL_BLEND)
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

   //gl draw functions (glDrawArrays,glDrawElements,etc..)

   glDisable(GL_BLEND)
   ```
3. Are you clearing the 2D texture binding before you swap buffers? i.e ...

   ```
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately including these changes did not make a difference. It seems to me that there is something wrong in loading the dds or the shader, maybe. If i set a fixed alpha-value for the gl_FragColor, transparency works. Only when loaded from the texture somethings going wrong.

Comment: OMG! I solved it. So stupid. At first I had the GL_BLEND enabled only for one part of the drawings, not the one that needed to be transparent. Then this was correct but the wrong texture was loaded. Sorry for bothering you. And thanks again for your help. I had already given up on this. :D